# onOpen trigger not being activated on Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

The onOpen event on my Google Form is being activated only when I open the form for edition, but not when I open it to answer (/viewform). Actually, I just want it to run when someone opens the form to answer, because my script updates a combobox with current information from a table. I'm not sure if that is the best way to do it, but I'm open to suggestions.

I tried both creating a function onOpen() and also creating a doIt() function and manually adding a trigger to onOpen on the Resources > Add Trigger menu. The Trigger is listed correctly and seems to be working as opening the form for edition updates it properly. Probably I got the wrong trigger handler then, but there are no others for what I want (just onEdit, that should do what onOpen is doing, and onInstall).

The docs for this are incredibly succinct, and absolutely focused on Spreadsheets scripts. They mention custom hooks, however, called Installable Triggers, and one of them is actually:

> When a spreadsheet or the form editor is opened. (Note that this trigger does not activate when a user opens a form to respond, but rather when an editor opens the form to modify it.) Unlike the simple trigger onOpen, the installable trigger can act as the user who installed the trigger.

Which suggests that onOpen should do exactly what I want... So now I am very confused.

Also, I'm not sure how the permissions will work. For now, as far as I can see, it seems that anyone to whom I share the form is able to edit it, and everyone can answer it, as long as the person has the URL. Is there a way to whitelist people to answer it? I don't quite like the URL being the only barrier stopping outsiders to see the data I'm loading into the combobox, and, most important, update this data by submitting the form... It seems brute-force could easily unravel a lot of 'secret' forms this way... Or is it ok, from a security standpoint, and I am just mad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trigger you need to install is not an `onOpen` but an `onFormSubmit`.
is shows up in the *script editor/ressources/current script trigger*

see illustration below
[image]

As you have read (but aparently not understood), the `onOpen` trigger fires only when someone opens the form editor, not when someone fills in (submits) the form.

About the second point, there is no way to whitelist users that would be allowed to fill a form, all you can do is to select the answers based on used names and eventually reject answers that you don't allow.

If this access control is really vital for you you could achieve something quite efficient using UiApp or HTML service but that would be a bit more complex.

Concerning your last point about permissions, things are very simple : **installable triggers run as the user who created the trigger**. If you did then the script will run as if you ran it manually, using your priviledges and access rights.

Comment: That wouldn't work as well, because I want the combobox to be filled with items when the user opens the form for answering, so he can choose one, not when he submits it (that would be too late)... I tried, nonetheless, and it didn't work. Again, I'm not sure if this trigger exists, but I am open to other ways to make dynamic comboboxes (select/options or multiple choice questions, that is)...

Comment: the workflow you describe seems not possible to achieve ... do you mean that your script creates this comboBox ? if yes hten form is not the right way to do it... build it with UiApp or htmlService

Comment: Yes, it basically populates the combobox with the data from a spreadsheet. Basically what I want to do is a dynamic combobox, that loads it's items from a Spreadsheet. Like a list of people or something like that. And it always has to be an up-to-date list.

Comment: Wow, that is terrible! I had this whole system idea in my mind, strongly dependent on this feature... Well, thanks for the answers!

Comment: ;-) Try UiApp, it is not very complicated and you'll find a lot of end-to-end examples on this site (I published a few ones... btw, thx for accepting:)

Comment: The answer is marked correct but onFormSubmit is not for what this question asks (updating the options in a combobox)

Comment: I marked it as correct as @Sergeinsas indicated that what I was trying to accomplish is impossible, and therefore rendered my question unanswerable. Maybe he could update his answer to add this conversation we had in the comments, or maybe someone find a workaround, and then I shall update the accepted answer accordingly :)

Comment: What is the point of a script triggers onOpen but only works in development but not in real scenario? What were Google thinking when they decided to limit onOpen to during form development only? This has completely messed up my plans as well as the original poster's. Sorry, but just can't not express this.

Comment: Same here, they should have mentioned better in their docs. I've spent like 20 hours working on a system that is not gonna fly because of this stupid limitation. Form triggers are pretty much crippled atm

Answer (score 0):

I think that the trick to this is to setup the your script to trigger on the edit of the spreadsheet where the data that populates the form exists. You would probably need to check in the `onEdit(e)` event to see if you actually need to act such as checking the event object for what was edited. This way, as soon as you update the source data, the form us updated for you (vs when the form is opened).

Comment: It sounds as if the OP is needs to check the logged in user, in order to choose the items to include in the populated options and therefore this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish your intent, but instead trigger from open FormView, which will **overcall** functions, and its not the correct way to do.
You need to make a trigger to the spreadsheet data source, to check if data was change and then fill values.

Example: To the Spreadsheet data Source, make a Trigger to Change data.

```
    function OnDataChange()
{
   let form = FormApp.openById("YourformID"); 
/* 
   or if data source are also linked to form, you could do this: 
   ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
   form = FormApp.openByUrl(ss.getFormUrl());
 */

   let names = ss.getSheetByName("Names").getDataRange().getValues().map(x => x[0]).slice(1);
   FillItem(form,"Name",names)
   
} 
function FillItem(form,itemtitle,values)
{
  form.getItems().filter(el => el.getTitle()==itemtitle)
      .forEach( el => { 
           switch(el.getType()) {
             case FormApp.ItemType.LIST:
                  el.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values);
                  break;
             case FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE:
                  el.asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoiceValues(values);
                  break;
           }
      })
}
```

Change the above **switch** according yours needs.