# Have a Google Form set the title to the users email

Tags: javascript, dynamic, google-apps-script, google-forms

I'd like to make a Google Form that I can email to multiple people and when they open the form to fill it out, the title will be replaced with their email.

I've tried the onOpen() trigger and from what I understand it doesn't act the way its name suggests.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you so much!
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onOpen triggers when the form is opened for editing by the developer (you), not for submission by the end users ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24370438/943814)).

I don't know of a way to do what you want. The closest I can think of is using apps script to generate the same form over and over again from a list of email addresses. But then you'd have to send a different form to each person, which I'm guessing isn't going to work for you.

Comment: I was afraid there'd be no way to do it. Do you have any suggestions for other form services I can use to accomplish this? Thanks

Comment: Nope, google is the only one I've used. For my project I'll be switching to a custom solution building the forms myself in HTML. Just don't have time to do it at the moment.